# css set border-radius relative to height

Tags: css

As i understand it, in CSS the `border-radius` property defines how far down a side a rounded corner should start. The distance can be in relative units, such as `%`. However, when set in percent CSS of course take % of width on the x-axis and % of height on y. I want the element to be a bar with rounded ends:

```
div {
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 800px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px; /* hardcoded, but would like it to be 50% of height */
}
```

Pair this with an standard html doc with just a single empty `div` in the body. In the actual case i need this for, the height of the div is also a percentage, so i cannot just calculate it manually. How can i set the border radius to 50% of height on both axes? I couldn't seem to find this neither asked or done anywhere, so maybe there is a really obvious way of doing this that i'm just missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use:

```
border-radius: 50vh;
```

> Seems like when provided higher value of `radius` working for different `width` and `height` values.

```css
div {
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  /* hardcoded, but would like it to be 50% of width */
  border-radius: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: that would be the same hack, except with relative units that are always large enough, right?

Comment: Yep, I just tried giving width of 1200px and height of 1000px, hope this testing is sufficient!

Comment: This is a little misleading. The reason it works is like Dave pointed out. It just needs to be a large amount. If you put 20vh, chances are it will work too (unless your element is huge too). Going with like 1000000px probably better conveys the fact that it has to be a ridiculously large amount.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit of a cheat, but you can just set the border-radius to something huge and it will end up looking the same regardless of the size:

```
div {
    border-radius: 500px;
}
```

Comment: good enough for me, i'll just add a comment to explain it to later me.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) or pre-processor variables(like in sass, less...), if you don't want to hardcode it

```css
div {
    --height: 150px; /* can be percentage too */
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 800px;
    height: var(--height);
    border-radius: calc(var(--height) * 0.5); /* 50% of height */
}
```

I don't think Manjuboyz's answer's your question. The main question was setting border-radius as 50% of the container's height, not the viewport's.

`vh` converts to the viewport's height, not the container's height.

Look at these:
[css tricks - Fun with viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/),
[mdn docs for vh](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh)